# Insert data into join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, `USER`, `ROLE` and `USER_ROLE`.

`USER_ROLE` is a join table between `USER` and `ROLE` and looks like this:

```
USER_ID | ROLE_ID
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
2       | 2
...
```

I want to write some SQL that inserts every role once for each user. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a cross join:

```
insert into user_role(user_id, role_id)
    select u.user_id, r.role_id
    from user u cross join role r;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Also noticed it seems to work as `...from user u, role r` without the `cross join`. Are they equivalent?

Comment: That`s an implicit cross join.In the answer is explicit.

Comment: @rcgeorge23 . . . The `,` is equivalent to a `cross join`.  But, in my opinion, `from` clauses should never contains commas, so the `cross join` is better.